# Are there any good mplayer tutorials?

Tags: mplayer, documentation

Are there any good mplayer tutorials aimed at newbies? I know about `man mplayer`, but it's too complex to start from there.

*Please don't suggest using any mplayer front ends!*

Comment: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/documentation.html

Comment: What do you want to do? Play videos?

Comment: @georg playing and encoding videos